# Decomposing representations of $SU(n_1 n_2)$ into $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$

Tags: representation-theory

I am wondering whether there is a systematic way to decompose a certain representation (say the completely symmetric representation for concreteness) of $SU(n_1n_2)$ in terms of the representations of $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$.

For instance, let $n_1=2$ and $n_2=3$ i.e., $n_1n_2=6$. Consider a fully symmetric representation of $SU(6)$ with dimension **56**. This can be decomposed into representations of $SU(2)\times SU(3)$ as:

**56**= (**4**,**10**) + (**2**,**8**)

The first entry in the parentheses is the dimension of the $SU(2)$ representation and the second one is the $SU(3)$ dimension. For more details of this, please have a look at 15th chapter of "Lie algebras of Particle Physics" by Georgi. There is a version online:
http://mural.uv.es/rusanra/Lie%20Algebras%20in%20Particle%20Physics%202%C2%AA%20ed%20-%20From%20Isospin%20to%20Unified%20Theories%20(Georgi,%201999).pdf

In the above example, as far as I understand, Georgi obtains the decomposition just by trail and error and counting the dimensions. My question is whether one can do this decomposition more systematically?

Comment: You could calculate the character of a diagonal matrix, that should always give you the decomposition.

Comment: What sort of embedding are you generally considering of the groups here? I don't see a natural choice to turn a pair consisting of an $n_1\times n_1$ matrix and an $n_2\times n_2$ matrix into an $(n_1n_2)\times (n_1n_2)$ matrix (instead of, say an $(n_1+n_2)\times (n_1+n_2)$ matrix).

Comment: @W.Schlieper  Thanks for the reply. Correct me if I am wrong. Isn't the character same thing as the dimension of the representation?  For small $n$'s, I can decompose the representations via comparing characters on both sides. But is it a viable strategy if $n_1$ and $n_2$ become large or if I am trying to decompose representations of $SU(n_1n_2n_3)$ into representations of $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)\times SU(n_3)$ as the number of combinations of dimensions possible increase rapidly?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am not from mathematics background and I don't know the answer to the question you asked. I am using the fact that $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$ is a subgroup of $SU(n_1n_2)$.What I am trying to achieve is to decompose a representation of $SU(n_1n_2)$ in terms of the representations of its subgroup- $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$.

Comment: But it will be a subgroup in many ways, so why would the decomposition not depend on which of these ways you choose? Also, the character is not the same as the dimension. In fact, labelling the representations by their dimension is an exceedingly poor idea once you go above $SU(3)$ or so, as you start to get way too many non-isomorphic ones of each dimension.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. You are saying that $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$ can be a subgroup of $SU(n_1n_2)$ in multiple ways, right? Also, I understand your comment about denoting the representations using dimensions.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you take a particular way of decomposing $SU(n_1n_2)$ into $SU(n_1)\times SU(n_2)$ and explain how the decomposition can be done?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm thinking that the natural choice wants is the one you get from the tensor product of the standard representations.

Comment: Also the character is more general than the dimension; it's the trace of specific elements, which at $1$ is the dimension.  Look up the Weyl character formula.

Comment: @W.Schlieper I checked out how to write the Weyl character  for certain representation of $SU(6)$. But how do I use that to get the decomposition into representations of $SU(2)\times SU(3)$?  Should I take some of the parameters in the character of $SU(6)$ to be zeroes?